# Action of 3x3 invertible matrices on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory

One of the many beautiful properties of mobius transformations includes the fact they form a natural map of equivalence classes (related by scalar multiplication of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}  \ \text{~} \  \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

This had got me wondering.. the space of meromorphic functions is pretty massive. Does there exist then a natural action of equivalence classes $3 \times 3$ complex matrices (up to multiplication by scalar) into complex functions?

I tried to explore and find some, outside of the mobius transformations and came across the group $z^{\theta}$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{C}, |\theta| = 1$ as an action of the circle group into the complex plane which generalizes naturally to the group $e^{\frac{a\log z +b}{c \log z + d}}$ (where $c=b=0$, $|a/d| =1$) corresponds to the circle group. But the general form suggests this isn't anything "new" from the mobius transformations we have already seen.

I suspect it may be possible there is no "elementary" set of functions (as in involving algebraic, and exponents), but then the problem gets a lot more complex since the space of meromorphic functions has a lot of exotic and complicated infinite series.

Comment: When  $\theta=-1$, the map $z\mapsto z^\theta$ is undefined at $z=0$. So you only have a meromorphic action not a holomorphic action of the circle group on the plane.

Comment: This is correct and an oversight on my part, let me edit the question.

Comment: To clarify you want automorphisms of the space of meromorphic functions as what? As a field?

Comment: Nope, much simpler, I'm looking for a set of meromorphic functions, as a group under composition.

Comment: There are a lot of meromorphic functions but not very many that are invertible.  In any case, do you have some particular domain in mind for your functions?  The entire Riemann sphere?  Some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 4):

Möbius transformations are the *only* meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ that are invertible with respect to composition.  So no, there is not any natural meromorphic group action on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ other than groups that have a natural homomorphism to the group $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ of Möbius transformations.

In particular, for the group $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})$ of complex $3\times 3$ invertible matrices modulo scalars, there does not exist any nontrivial continuous homomorphism $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})\to PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ at all.  This follows from the fact that $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})$ is a simple group, so any nontrivial homomorphism would be injective, but there cannot exist any continuous injection $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})\to PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ since $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})$ has higher dimension than $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$.  (In fact, I suspect the assumption of continuity can be dropped, though I don't see a way to prove it at the moment.  In any case, certainly any "natural" action would be continuous.)

The natural action of $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})$ is instead on the complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$: $GL_3(\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^3$ linearly, and thus also acts on the space $\mathbb{CP}^2$ of $1$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^3$, and this action descends to $PGL_3(\mathbb{C})$.  This is a direct generalization of the action of $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$, as $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ can be identified with $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and the action again just comes from the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

This remains a conjecture but I have good reason to believe the following will work:

Lets call this group of functions the $M_3$ transforms. We define them as the set of complex functions which send cubic plane curves to cubic plane curves.

To be concrete on what this means: we characterize our functions $M_3: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ instead as $M_3: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. 
Then in the cartesian plane given a cubic plane curve on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form

$$ Ax^3 + Bx^2y + Cxy^2 + Dy^3 + Ex^2 + Fxy + Gy^2 + Hx + Iy + J = 0$$

Where $A... J \in \mathbb{R}$ the image of this set under an element of $M_3$ will be:

$$ A_fx^3 + B_fx^2y + C_fxy^2 + D_fy^3 + E_fx^2 + F_fxy + G_fy^2 + H_fx + I_fy + J_f = 0$$

Where $A_f ... J_f \in \mathbb{R}$.

I claim that with a certain "niceness" condition that is yet to be found [ex: continuous] that this set of complex functions represents a natural action of $3\times 3$ matrices upon the complex plane.

### Why I think this might work:

Observe:

Mobius Group of Transformations is isomorphic $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$

The elements of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ can be represented by $2\times 2$ matrices and are determined entirely by their image of 2 vectors of size 2, however, this results in  4 equations (for each coordinate of the 2 complex vectors) for 3 unknowns (the topological dimension of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ is 3). So really each element of $PGL(2,\mathbb{C})$ can be uniquely identified with its action on 3 points on the complex plane [naturally then Mobius transformations are entirely determined by their action on 3 points in the complex plane, or riemann sphere since we now consider infinity to be a point].

Now it is not a coincidence that mobius transformations map generalized circles to generalized circles. A generalized circle (that is object of constant curvature) is ENTIRELY determined by 3 points.

So the idea is then that mobius transformation should be entirely determined by their actions on 3 points, and those 3 points have a unique generalized circle passing through them, and thus the mobius transformation should be entirely determined by their action on a generalized circle $C_1$, that is given a generalized circle $C_1$ what generalized circle $C_2$ does it get mapped to? That determines a mobius transformation uniquely.

We now have all the ingredients to lift this idea into the space of $3\times 3$ complex matrices. In this case i'm consider $GL(3,\mathbb{C})$ NOT $PSL(3, \mathbb{C})$ so these matrices are determined by their action on 3 vectors of size 3, or in other words 9 points in the complex plane.

So now I have a set of functions that need to be entirely determined by their action on 9 points in the complex plane. Through every 9 points there happens to pass a unique cubic curve. It is therefore natural for me to consider those functions which exclusively map cubic curves to cubic curves, since they will naturally form a group under composition.

What I need to now add is a condition [ex: continuity or meromorphicity etc... ] (but likely not meromorphicity due to @Eric Wofsey's findings) so that I restrict my space of all $f$'s to a set of functions that isn't so pathological that they are not UNIQUELY determined by their action on 9 points [I believe simply continuous except at isolated points might be sufficient]

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time thinking about this we have two of the following results:

There is a natural action of $3 \times 3$ real matrices on the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y  \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \frac{1}{gx+hy+i} \begin{bmatrix} ax+by+c \\ dx+ey+f \end{bmatrix} $$

(It's a lot of work algebraically but one can verify that composing such transformations respects matrix multiplication). This implies by considering a real part and imaginary part function, denoted as $\text{Re}(z)$  and $\text{Im}(z)$ then an action of $3\times 3$ real matrices can be realized as a mobius transformations is given as

$$ z \rightarrow \frac{ (a\text{Re}(z)+b\text{Im}(z)+c) + i (d\text{Re}(z)+e\text{Im}(z)+f)}{g\text{Re}(z)+h\text{Im}(z)+j}   $$

For your choice of 9 real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j$  (note that $i$ is also used for the imaginary constant so we skip it in the previous list).

But the introduction of real parts and imaginary parts this way is a little less than ideal, and this doesn't let us consider complex valued matrices.

### Developing a functional equation trick:

The mobius transformations can identified as a class of smooth solutions to the following functional equation

$$ f: \mathbb{C}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $$

$$ f(a,b,c,d,f(e,f,g,h,z)) = f(ae+bg, af+bh, ce+dg, cf+dh,z)$$

(I conjecture solution to this all are of the form $\Omega^{-1} \left(  \frac{a \Omega(z)+b}{c\Omega(z)+d} \right) $, for a choice of bijection $\Omega: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. The case of $\Omega$ being the identity are the usual mobius transforms we encounter).

This strategy should be able to easily scale to let us consider

$$ f: \mathbb{C}^{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $$

$$ f(A, f(B,z)) = f(AB, z) $$

where $A,B$ are $3 \times 3$ complex matrices that represent our 9 other arguments to $f$.

Developing strategies to extract solutions from these functional equations currently remains a mystery to me.